# Can a ListPointPlot3D be overlayed with map

Tags: geography, geographics, overlay

I am trying to make a graph of earthquakes (position and depth) shown on map of the country. The map is drawn with `Graphics3D` option with the code:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[1.5], 
  Map[Append[Reverse[#], 0] &, 
   EntityValue[Entity["Country", "Macedonia"], "Polygon"] /. 
    GeoPosition -> Identity, {-2}], Blue, Opacity[2]}, Axes -> True]
```

and using a txt file with the coordinates for position and depth of the events an `ListPointPlot3D` was made.

[image: the image of the separate graphs are shown]

I have problem to overlay the graphs to get a picture similar to this one.

[image: this is example with data exported with function EarthquakeData]

Can I get help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that ``Show[a, b]`` should work.

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geo-related-properties/visualize-depth-and-position-of-earthquakes.html

Comment: I have tried many options and the code given in the link, but the problem is that I am not using the EarthquakeData function for the coordinates and depths of the events. I have my own file of events and I can't load it at the Graphic3D part of the code. The problem is that I am not sure how the .txt file that is used as source should be formatted to be accepted by the code given in the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the data from `EarthquakeData` to your events list. The difference is that `EarthquakeData` uses `GeoPosition` for latitude and longitude, but your events are a simple list of latitude, longitude and depth. It's easy to convert the list to use `GeoPosition`. Then you can use the [Visualize Depth and Position of Earthquakes](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geo-related-properties/visualize-depth-and-position-of-earthquakes.html) demonstration code with your list of events.

I need some sample data. Convert `data` to use `GeoPosition`, then simply change `data` to `dataGeoPosition` in the demonstration code.

```
data = {{41.87, 22.09, 18.}, {41.96, 21.55, 5.}, {41.129, 20.987, 10.},
 {41.13, 20.83, 4.}, {41.2, 20.72, 15.}, {41.302, 20.864, 10.}, 
 {41.183, 21.196, 14.}, {41.158, 22.567, 10.}, {41.279, 20.884, 39.},
 {42.052, 21.257, 13.}};

dataGeoPosition = {GeoPosition@#[[;; 2]], Last[#]} & /@ data;

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6],
  Map[Append[Reverse[#], 0] &,
    EntityValue[Entity["Country", "Macedonia"], "Polygon"] /.
    GeoPosition -> Identity, {-2}],
  Blue, Opacity[1],
  Line[Apply[{Append[Reverse[First[#]], 0],
      Append[Reverse[First[#]], -#2]} &,
    dataGeoPosition, {1}]]},
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image: earthquake visualization]

We can use your events list without `GeoPosition` if we modify the demonstration code, and we get the same result.

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6],
    Map[Append[Reverse[#], 0] &,
      EntityValue[
          Entity["Country", "Macedonia"],
           "Polygon"] /. GeoPosition -> Identity, {-2}],
    Blue, Opacity[1],
    Line[{Append[Reverse[#[[;; 2]]], 0],
      Append[Reverse[#[[;; 2]]], -Last[#]]} & /@ data]},
  Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

Here's how you can use your original method that combines `Graphics3D` and `ListPointPlot3D`. Notice that all of these methods reverse latitude and longitude to preserve the correct orientation for `Graphics3D`.

```
a = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.6],
      Map[Append[Reverse[#], 0] &,
        EntityValue[
            Entity["Country", "Macedonia"], "Polygon"] /.
      GeoPosition -> Identity, {-2}]}, Axes -> True];
b = ListPointPlot3D[
  Append[Reverse[#[[;; 2]]], Last[#]] & /@ data,
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Thin];
Show[a, b, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image: earthquake visualization with ListPointPlot3D]